# No descarga el reporte y manda error al descargar

Tags: python, mvc, xml, odoo

En el modulo de odoo que genere el wizard para reportes avanzados estoy tratando de imprimir el reporte que genera la vista pero al descargarlo me manda un error ya que dice que hay un id externo que no encuentra  voy a adjuntar los 3 codigos como el modelo su vista y el reporte

Codigo python:

```
´´´# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json
import io
from xlsxwriter import workbook

from odoo.tools import date_utils
from odoo.exceptions import UserError, ValidationError
from odoo import fields, models, api

try:
from odoo.tools.misc import xlsxwriter
except ImportError:
import xlsxwriter



class ReporteEspecialCartaPorte (models.TransientModel):
_name=('reporte_mti_datos_generales_carta_porte')

consignment_note_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='mti.carta.porte', string='Carta Porte')
product_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='product.template', string='Producto')
partner_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='res.partner', string='Remitente')
consignee_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='res.partner', string='Consignee')
invoice_mti = fields.Char(string='Factura')
arrival_notification = fields.Char(string='Notificacion de llegada')


def get_datos_generales_report(self):
    data = {
        'consignment_note_id': self.consignment_note_id,
        'product_id': self.product_id,
        'partner_id': self.partner_id,
        'consignee_id': self.consignee_id,
        'invoice_mti': self.invoice_mti,
        'arrival_notification': self.arrival_notification
    }
    return self.env.ref('mti_report_cp.datos_generales').report_action(self, 
 data=data)´´´
```

asi es como tengo el modelo ya que como recupera informacion de un modelo externo al modulo use el transient model y abstract model pero no se si en los otros dos codigos este mal

vista del popup:

```
´´´<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<odoo>
<record id="informe_cp_wizard" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Informe_cp</field>
    <field name="model">reporte_mti_datos_generales_carta_porte</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form >
               <group >
                <field name="consignment_note_id" widget="Many2one_tags"/>
                <field name="product_id" widget="Many2one_tags"/>
                <field name="partner_id" widget="Many2one_tags"/>
               </group>
              <group>
                <field name="consignee_id" widget="Many2one_tags"/>
                <field name="invoice_mti"/>
                <field name="arrival_notification"/>
              </group>
            <footer>
                <button name="get_datos _report" string="PDF Report" type="object" 
 class="btn-primary"/>
            </footer>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>

 <record id="mti_informe_cp_report" model="ir.actions.act_window">
<field name="name">Informe de datos generales de carta porte</field>
<field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
<field name="res_model">reporte_mti_datos_generales_carta_porte</field>
<field name="view_mode">form</field>
<field name="target">new</field>
 </record>
     </odoo>´´´
```

y asi es como defini la vista del popup

adjunto codigo del reporte:

```
´´´?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

 <odoo>
 <report id="action_datos_generales"
         model="reporte_mti_datos_generales_carta_porte"
         string="Informe de datos generales de Carta Porte"
         report_type="qweb-pdf"
         file="mti_report_cp.datos_generales_view"
         name="mti_report_cp.datos_generales_view"
 />

<template id="datos_generales_view">
    <t t-call="web.html_container">
<t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <img
          src="/mti_report_cp/static/src/img/logo.png"
          style="max-height: 90px; margin-left: 30px"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2" style="margin-left: 150px; padding-top: 50px">
        <h5 style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold; font-size: 50px">
          Datos generales Carta Porte
        </h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <table class="table table-sm" style="border: 1px solid #939e9d; border-collapse: collapse">
                <tr class=" " style="border: 1px solid #939e9d; font-size: 13px">
                    <td name="consignment_note_id" class="text-left" style="border: 1px solid #939e9d; padding-left: 20px"><strong>Carta_Porte:</strong><t t-if="o.consignment_note_id"><span t-field="o.consignment_note_id" /></t></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class=" " style="border: 1px solid #939e9d; font-size: 13px">
                    <td name="product_id" class="text-left" style="border: 1px solid #939e9d; padding-left: 20px"><strong>Producto:</strong><t t-if="o.product_id"><span t-field="o.consignment_note_id" /></t></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class=" " style="border: 1px solid #939e9d; font-size: 13px">
                    <td name="partner_id" class="text-left" style="border: 1px solid #939e9d; padding-left: 20px"><strong>Remitente:</strong><t t-if="o.partner_id"><span t-field="o.partner_id" /></t></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class=" " style="border: 1px solid #939e9d; font-size: 13px">
                    <td name="consignee_id" class="text-left" style="border: 1px solid #939e9d; padding-left: 20px"><strong>Consignatario:</strong><t t-if="o.consignee_id"><span t-field="o.consignee_id" /></t></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class=" " style="border: 1px solid #939e9d; font-size: 13px">
                    <td name="invoice_mti" class="text-left" style="border: 1px solid #939e9d; padding-left: 20px"><strong>Factura:</strong><t t-if="o.invoice_mti"><span t-field="o.invoice_mti" /></t></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class=" " style="border: 1px solid #939e9d; font-size: 13px">
                    <td name="arrival_notification" class="text-left" style="border: 1px solid #939e9d; padding-left: 20px"><strong>Notificacion de llegada:</strong><t t-if="o.arrival_notification"><span t-field="o.arrival_notification" /></t></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</t>
    </t>
</template>
</odoo>´´´
```

y esa es la estrucutra que tengo del reporte no se si sea esa la que este mal o alguno de los otros dos codigos pero la terminal y la interfaz de odoo mandan el error ahi no se si tenga que cmabiar la estructura del rpeorte porque esta el modelo esta llamando la informacion de forma diferente o como seria ahi?

este es el error que manda

´´´´Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/odoo14.0/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 639, in _handle_exception
return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
File "/opt/odoo14.0/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 315, in _handle_exception
raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
ValueError: External ID not found in the system: mti_report_cp.datos_generales´´´´

eso manda al presionar el boton para descarga el archivo en pdf

Comment: El id debería ser `mti_report_cp.datos_generales_view` según lo que publicaste.

Comment: @Legna segun esto el error creo esta en el codigo de pytho es esta linea

´´´return self.env.ref('mti_report_cp.datos_generales').report_action(self, 
 data=data)´´´´